# Возвращение к якорю при нажатии кнопки назад

Tags: jquery

как сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку назад скрол был на другую страницу с якорем #links123. Откуда собственно и начинался переход

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
         $('body').on('click','#nav-load a',function(){
        var urlNext = $(this).attr('href');
        var scrollNext = $(this).offset().top - 200;
        if (urlNext !== undefined) {
            $.ajax({
                url: urlNext,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    ShowLoading('');
                },            
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#bottom-nav').remove();
                    $('#dle-content').append($('#dle-content', data).html());
                    $('#dle-content').after($('#bottom-nav'));
                    window.history.pushState("", "", urlNext);
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollNext}, 800);    
                    HideLoading('');
                },
                  error: function() {                
                    HideLoading('');
                    alert('что-то пошло не так');
                  }
            });
        };
        return false;
    });
    
});
```

Проблема вроде в этой строчке

```
window.history.pushState("", "", urlNext);
```

Comment: В заголовке у вас про якорь, а вопрос про кнопку "назад"...

Comment: так и правильно. якорем идет переход на страницу объявления. и нужно вернуть к нему при нажатии кнопки назад

Comment: Понятно. Только в вопросе написано немного другое. Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Исправил вопрос, помогите будьте добры

Comment: я думаю проблема в window.history.pushState("", "", urlNext);

Comment: а сейчас это как работает?

Comment: кидает в самый низ страницы. Поправил еще вопрос

Comment: а чего вы ожидаете?

Comment: что при нажатии кнопки назад вернется на то место, где был осуществлен переход

Comment: так как содержимое меняется вручную, а стандартным механизмом скролл может работать не совсем корректно, так как запоминает значение когда данные подгрузились. Можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону [события `onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) и  делать скролл внутри него

Comment: не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз, лучше отредактировать предыдущий